# how to keep the bar seekbar when exiting the application, and then on again retains its previous state

Tags: android

How to keep the bar Seek bar when exiting the application, and then on again retains its previous state.Does anyone have the code for this function ? Where can I add code ?Thank you so much . This is my code :

```
seekBarP.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            int progress = 0;

            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int timeRunP, boolean fromUser) {
                progress = timeRunP;
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                textViewP.setText("Index : " + progress + "/" + seekBarP.getMax());
            }
        });
        btnOK.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton arg0, boolean isChecked) {
                if (btnOK.isChecked()) {
                    SharedPreferences pre1 = getSharedPreferences("SavingPreferences", MODE_PRIVATE);
                    final int values = pre1.getInt("key", 0);
                    final int values1 = pre1.getInt("key1", 0);
                    if (values == 0 && values1 == 0) {
                        Processing();
                        long[] run = {0, seekBarS.getProgress(), seekBarP.getProgress()};
                        vibrator.vibrate(run, 0);
                        ShowNotification();
                    } else {
                        textViewS.setText("Index: " + values + "/" + seekBarS.getMax() + "(s)");
                        textViewP.setText("Index:  " + values1 + "/" + seekBarP.getMax() + "(s)");
                        long[] run = {0, values, values1};
                        vibrator.vibrate(run, 0);
                        ShowNotification();
                    }
                    SharedPreferences pre = getSharedPreferences("SavingPreferences", MODE_PRIVATE);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pre.edit();
                    editor.putInt("key", seekBarS.getProgress());
                    editor.putInt("key1", seekBarP.getProgress());
                    editor.commit();
                } else {
                    long[] off = {0, 0, 100};
                    vibrator.vibrate(off, 0);
                    CancelNotification();
                    moveTaskToBack(true);

                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

in onPause() save the current progress obtained by

(int) seekBarP.getProgress(), into a shared preference object.

Then in onCreate check the shared preference for a value and when you initialize your seekbar call seekBarP.setProgress(savedValue).

If you need more info will have to be later i am supposed to be working:)